# Can this PHP rounding down be written more elegantly?

Tags: php

We would like to round down an integer number already constrained to be at least 1 to 1, 5, 15, 25, 50, 100. This is what I came up with:

```
function roundDown($count) {
  $prev = 1;
  foreach ([5, 15, 25, 50, 100] as $limit) {
    if ($count < $limit) {
      return $prev;
    }
    $prev = $limit;
  }
  return 100;
}
```

Its working but, I do not feel good about it.

Comment: This is something new that I'm seeing. A paranthesis inside the function argument?

Comment: I am also confused about `$count(` ??

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /var/www/html/public//test.php on line 3

Comment: "it works but"
No it doesn't work

Comment: He just put the wrong parentheses there. The solution looks fine for what you are looking for. And answer below makes it a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function roundDown($count) {
  foreach ([100, 50, 25, 15, 10, 5, 1] as $limit) {
    if ($count >= $limit) {
      return $limit;
    }
  }
  return $limit;
}
```

Feel better?

Comment: You can probably return just 1 at the end as $limit looks out of scope or not very nice there.

Comment: Since we know $count is at least 1 the second return won't be necessary. I must be half asleep to not think of that.

Comment: @MarkSkayff Hmm yeah, but this way abstracts "1" to <last item in list>. Avoids a connascence. Pretty minor either way. But actually as mentioned that return will only be hit if the stated precond $count >= 1 does not hold..

Comment: My solution prints 15 at 15 not 25. The site you linked is funny or something.

Comment: oh my bad.. there was a typo sorry

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
return max(array_filter([100, 50, 25, 15, 5, 1], function ($x) use ($count) { return $x < $count; }) ?: [1]);
```

happens to also work but it's not particularly readable.